# Largest open-source dictionary w/ brief definitions (not wiktionary)

Tags: dictionaries

What's the largest open-source dictionary that includes brief 
definitions of each word? Wiktionary is a great resource but:

- There are over 200K words in the scowl list that aren't in 
  wiktionary. I'd use scowl directly, but it only list words and has no 
  definitions.
- Wiktionary intentionally includes misspellings (sometimes not 
  marked as such, and sometimes as redirection), and I'm looking for 
  only correctly-spelled words.
- Wiktionary's definitions are often lengthy, not brief.
- It's difficult to automatically extract the portion of a wiktionary 
  page that's the definition.

I'm somewhat surprised this question isn't in the FAQ, and that I couldn't 
find the answer by searching this site.

Comment: Could you provide a link for this "scowl list"? I've not heard of it before.

Comment: http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I just compared the last wordlist (all "words" files) to [enwiktionary-20151102-all-titles](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/20151102/enwiktionary-20151102-all-titles-in-ns0.gz) and there are 240k words "missing" from Wiktionary, of which 80k are just duplicates of actual words + "'s" ending and so on. Only 176 words are missing from the "medium" list, 3k from the large, 38k from the huge. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Requested_entries_%28English%29/Wordlist

Comment: What is a "scowl list"?

Comment: wordlist.sourceforge.net

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Answer (score 23):

You may be looking for [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/), a lexical database for English developed by Princeton's Computer Science department. It has a [permissive license](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/license-and-commercial-use) allowing free use even in commercial applications. However, WordNet [does not have “closed-class” words](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/frequently-asked-questions), including pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions, determiners, and particles.

Answer (score 3):

The moreofit web site can be a good start to find sites similar to, here, wiktionary:

[**www.moreofit.com/similar-to/en.wiktionary.org/Top_10_Sites_Like_Wiktionary_En**](http://www.moreofit.com/similar-to/en.wiktionary.org/Top_10_Sites_Like_Wiktionary_En/)

The result includes **[dict.org](http://www.dict.org)**, which can be of interest considering what you are after.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that WordNet is a pretty good source for definitions. I have started to build a [multilingual dictionary (Deect)](http://deect.com/) on top of WordNet's English words and definitions (actually included a few more things), and the users usually like the definitions from WordNet.

Comment: I wonder why such awesome site is closed.

Comment: I would be great if you would release the project as open source, would you consider creating an organization on github? I would be willing to contribute, clean data, help maintain it etc.

Comment: seriously, give this to the community....you can store it on open data stack exchange's repository at datahub.io

Comment: I have just started a project like this (quite early stage) with MIT license:
https://github.com/poetyi/translator-app