# Is there any statistical data about English languange?

Tags: programming, dictionaries

*Not sure if this is on topic, feel free to migrate it, close it or delete it, it's the first time here, i found the programming tag so I give it a shot.*

Is it possible to download some sort of a dictionary which offers statistics about English language:

- How many verbs are there? and list them
- How many nouns are there? and list them
- How many adjectives and so on
- What is the synonym for x

In such a way that you can quickly access what you're looking for, and quickly tell if x is a verb or noun and what is the synonym for x and so on

Suppose y is a column that lists all the verbs, if a user input a word, i search y, if the word exists in y then it's a verb.

Comment: I don't see the utility of knowing exactly how many verbs etc. (words) there are in the English language. Practically any noun, nowadays can be transformed into a verb, and every day new expressions and nouns are being added: "Twerking" and "Selfie" are just two recent additions in the Oxford English Dictionary. Dictionaries in any case, will tell you if a word is an adjective, a noun, an adverb or all three etc. and they will also provide a few synonyms, more importantly they will tell you the cognates of that word and the typical collocations.

Comment: I imagine all online dictionaries arrange their data in more or less the way you describe internally. You could conceivably download their data and parse their database. However, as Mari-Lou said, that is pointless since it is so easy in English to make a verb from a noun.

Comment: [Verbing weirds language.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)) Who's to say that "verb" or "weird" are never valid as verbs?

Comment: That's languaging for you.

Comment: i know it's hard to tell exactly what's a verb and what's not, `i love love` is an example, but just for a starting point, adverbs or anything at all.

Comment: I'd suggest migrating this post to meta.

Comment: This might be of help, answers to "Largest open-source dictionary w/ brief definitions (not wiktionary)"  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/largest-open-source-dictionary-w-brief-definitions-not-wiktionary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As FumbleFingers mentioned, what would you count as a verb? The same concept can be applied to nouns. For example `A difficult sprint to the finish line` In this instance, sprint works as a noun, and this can apply to many verbs.

Because our language changes so rapidly, it would make almost any non-dynamic diagram or statistic obsolete within days. I was unable to find statistics for words by part of speech, but if anyone does find one, post it in the comments or edit this question.

Also, some resources:

- Synonyms can be found at [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/), [Synonyms.com](http://www.synonym.com/), etcetera.
- If you want to browse the occurrence statistics of words over time, try [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams).

Hope this helps.