# Open source word database with semantic information

Tags: dictionaries

I am looking for an open source word database for French and English that contain information beyond the grammatical category (noun, verb, etc). I need information such as whether a word is an object, an action etc. I know of the [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) databse as well as [Lexique 3](http://www.lexique.org/outils/Manuel_Lexique.htm#_Toc152122354), but they don't have that kind of information.

Comment: Object = noun; action = verb. That part of the question is unclear. French is off-topic here. This question appears to be a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8233/largest-open-source-dictionary-w-brief-definitions-not-wiktionary

Comment: Sorry for the unclearness :) By action, object, etc, I meant "themes or concepts". But afterwards I think the simplest answer is "make your own" since such annotations probably wouldn't exist in any open source dictionary. As for the duplicate, I don't quite agree with you. I didn't ask for definitions or grammatical categories since as mentioned I already have them.

Comment: Wordnet has all lot of extra information beyond POS, it just may not be the exact info you are seeking. I'd suggest that maybe the specific things you want could be derived programmatically from what's already in WordNet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this do you?

https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysqlenglishdictionary/

It's not that comprehensive, but I imagine if you are looking for higher standards, then you will most likely have to pay for it, or make your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I think I will make my own, it is probably the easiest way.